# Playing Am pentatonic scale over A blues chord progression

Tags: scales, improvisation, blues

I had a guitar entrance exam yesterday regarding improvisation. The guy put on a A blues backing track and told me to improvise.
As I'm not a blues guy myself, I went and improvised on the A major scale (Ionian mode). After a few seconds he stopped me and asked me if I was playing on the pentatonic, I said no and that I'm currently playing on the Ionian mode. He told me that the pentatonic is more appropriate to blues and to play on it. I said ok and proceeded to play on the F# minor pentatonic scale, since its A major's relative minor. He stopped me again and told me to play the A minor pentatonic scale, saying that's what gives it the blues feel- playing the minor scale on a major chord progression (Am pentatonic on A blues chord progression).
He failed me at the test (even tho my improv wasn't anything close to bad).

Note: this was not a 'blues improvisation exam', but simply an improvisation exam.

Now my question; was my 'mistake' that serious? Yes, I'm not a blues guy and my improv was not so bluesy probably, but still, failing me felt totally out of the blue.

*Edit for clarification, since this came out more as a rant:* Is it obvious and known that minor pentatonic should be played on major chord progression (Am pentatonic on top of A) in blues, and are other scales (pentatonic on relative minor/other modes) used as much in blues improvisation.

Comment: I think the obvious answer is that yes, in the eyes of the adjudicator, your mistake was that serious. But I'm not clear on exactly what your question is. Are you asking why you failed the exam? Are you asking what would be expected at a blues gig? There's a lot of information missing here — especially what the purpose and extent of the audition was.

Comment: @Aaron Yes you're correct. I guess my question is- is it obvious and known that minor pentatonic should be played on major chord progression (Am pentatonic on top of A) in blues, and are other scales (pentatonic on relative minor/other modes) used as much in blues improvisation. I'll edit my question since its unclear.

Comment: Just out of interest, what exam board, what grade?

Comment: 'Failing me felt totally out of the blue,' - gettit?

Comment: @Tim It was an entrance exam for a music school. I dont live in the US so I doubt any further info is helpfull. I passed overall but failed this part.

Comment: A lot of us don't live in US either. So it might be of use in an answer. It'll be useful for personal anecdotes, maybe.

Comment: The backing track presumably had dominant 7th chords A7 D7 E7, which is why A Ionian was a wrong choice - there are note clashes between your scale and the chords, and those clashes are not the same ones that make something sound bluesy.  F# minor pentatonic has the same problem e.g. when you get to the D7.  You could play the corresponding A/D/E mixolydian over each chord and it would at least have no clashes and be not-wrong. There's no single (common) scale that fits across all 3 chords without clashes, so choice is between following the chords and/or picking clashes that fit the idiom.

Comment: @Sapper What blues tunes have you played, can you give a few links? I read your question and honestly thought, "has this person ever heard, let alone played, any blues at all." IMO, music and particularly improvisation, is learned by listening and playing. Blues idioms and stylistic features are behind many other genres, and I think it's important to know them. For example, dominant-seventh harmony being used as "tonic" which isn't expected to resolve anywhere.

Comment: How much exposure have you had to blues music as a *listener*?

Comment: Expanding on the above comment by @blueskiwi: The *less-common* scale that fits *all three* chords is the "Blues Enneatonic (9-tone)", a.k.a. [Raga Malgunji](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/3773)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I dont listen to blues, nor did I ever really learn blues licks/songs. The only real exposure I had/have to blues is when I improvise to a blues backing track once in a blue moon. This explains why I didnt know the basics really. I learned all my life classical music and havent strayed from it too much.

Comment: I don't know what the entry exam tried to find out, but I could imagine one of the criteria being to see if you could not only produce notes but to play something that fits the style. For a guitarist, rudimentary knowledge of stylistic features of blues could reasonably be expected, IMO. It's not just about selecting the right scale, there are many "bluesy" aspects that can be found in other styles, and the easiest way build a blues vocabulary is to play blues. Is this blues? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ_TzhblPjw There's a lot of blues _in it_, but a lot of other things as well.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Yes, I think you're right about the criteria. Before he stopped me the last time he commented "That's not really blues but whatever". I havent played anything out of scale to my ears, but what I played was without a doubt- not blues. Thanks for the input.

Comment: "even tho my improv wasn't anything close to bad" - how do you know that? :-)

Comment: @BartoszKP I'm fairly confident in my skills.

Comment: @Theodore that is an interesting scale, and only lacks the b5 and b2 (b5 of the V) to make it a "comprehensive" blues scale. But I really meant a scale that has no avoid notes across all three chords, i.e. the notes in common from the 3 mixolydians... apparently this is called a "Scottish Pentatonic" https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/677 ... TIL!

Comment: @blueskiwi I see what you meant now.  BTW On the Scottish Pentatonic page, scroll down to the "Common Names" and you'll see it's also known by some [who?] as "blues major", and by many other names around the world.  It's of course just a mode of the major pentatonic.

Comment: @Theodore aha, nice!

Comment: @Sapper I can see that. But why do you think one's confidence is enough to self-judge in a meaningful way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a variety of scales that can be used in blues improvisation, depending somewhat on the specific style involved. However, using a A minor pentatonic over an A blues is the most basic. It's a very typical first scale taught in blues improvisation, and it would be reasonably expected in an audition or examination that this would be known.

An A major blues contains three main chords: A7, D7, and E7. The A minor pentatonic — A C D E G — contains pitches common to those chords so provides a simple way to begin improvising. A slightly more advanced improviser might use the A minor pentatonic over the A7 chord, then switch to different scales for the D7 and E7.

There are also blues scales, mixolydian scales, and bebop scales, all of which are frequently used in blues (or jazz) improvisation.

Blues itself comes in many variations with many different chords and alterations to those chords, so there is a corresponding proliferation of scales that could be used.

Comment: Its so basic yet I had no idea. I always thought to find the relative minor for the pentatonic whenever I met with blues, that this is how its done. Appreciate the info.

Comment: "then switch to D minor pentatonic over D7" ...no I don't think so, that would sound wrong for the IV chord.  E minor pentatonic over the E7 (the V chord) yes, but not on the IV chord, stick with A minor pentatonic for the D7.  Basically the "minor melody over major chord" sound of blues only applies to the I and the V. Soloing-wise the IV chord is more like an extension of the I chord, the 7th giving it a more minor-key flavour (from perspective of the I chord, the home key).

Comment: @blueskiwi - funny, cos that's worked for loads of us for decades ('switch to Dm pent for D7'). Why the heck wouldn't it work? If Am pent works over A7 and Em pent over E7, then Dm pent *has* to work over D7. And it always has. And always will. Yes, stick with Am pent over D7, but, boring. Several notes belong to both, though...

Comment: it sounds wrong and inept on a major key blues, that only works for "minor key" blues where the chords are minor too. the IV chord does not have a minor/major clash like the I and V do, in idiomatic blues

Comment: I have to chime in and agree with blueskiwi. It logically makes sense to say Dm pent works over D7 but as a IV chord the F creates a rub with the key of A to my ear. Blues players tend to improvise over tonalities as opposed to chords like jazz players do. If making a change my preferred option is to use A major pent over the I then switch to Am pent for the IV.

Comment: @blueskiwi has it right for exactly the reason JohnBelzaguy gives. I've updated the post.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - we'll agree to differ. There's only one note different, as I said. Am pent - ACDEG, Dm pent DFGAC. Lose the E, and play F instead. That F is the m3 of the D chord, and just like we'd bend C up to C#, we can bend F up to F#. Not including it denies us that capability. It's Blues after all.

Comment: @Tim the Am pent gives you 2 great neighboring tones to the D, E and C. If I want an F# I bend up a step from the E, nothing is denied. The F over D7 doesn’t work for me in A major blues. In minor I’ll take the F all day. As you said, we’l agree to differ.

Comment: "That F is the m3 of the D chord, and just like we'd bend C up to C#, we can bend F up to F#." ...but the context is different. The blues tonality occurs within the context of the chord sequence, it's not a rule you blindly apply to any dominant 7th wherever. The m3 of the IV chord scale is an avoid note in major-key blues. OTOH the m3 of the I chord matches the 7th of the IV, and the m3 of the V matches the 7th of the I.  Blues is more a superposition of tonalities with contextual emphasis/de-emphasis rather than a series of scales that move strictly in step with the chords.

Comment: @blueskiwi I think you meant to "@" Tim...?

Comment: @Aaron yes, sorry

Comment: @blueskiwi No apology needed. I'm just suggesting you might re-post your comment so that Tim sees it.

Comment: @blueskiwi - I've seen it, and stick with what I wrote. It's an age old trick to play a phrase a couple of times (over the 1st 4 bars), then repeat 5 frets higher over the IV for the next, and so on. Without what I wrote, that's a lot harder to do.

Answer (score 6):

It's common to use the minor pent. over a Blues, and most Blues will use major, or more likely dominant seventh chords throughout. Major pent. will work, but won't sound too bluesy. It'll sound fine over the tonic (I), but not work over IV or V so well. You moving to F♯m pent. gave you exactly the same set of notes,(as A major pent.)  no wonder he stopped you again!

Your teacher should have warned you that minor pent. works over both major *and* minor Blues songs, but major pent. will not work over minor Blues.

The main notes that make something Blues are ♭3, ♭5 and ♭7, (the 1st and last of which occur in minor pent.); none of which you would be using with major pent. No wonder he stopped you. You should still have played a decent solo over the sequence, but it wouldn't have sounded too bluesy.

Blues players will usually mix major and minor pents. in their playing, adding bends to particular notes. These would be expected in someone asked to improvise over a Blues sequence. And probably there was none of that, as the notes you stuck to didn't allow that to happen. Or maybe you bent notes that shouldn't need bending?